# Computing MVP matrix in vertex shader opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I calculated the MVP matrix in main code and THEN I moved the calculations into vertex shader.

Finally it doesn't work anymore. Why? There are no different in calculations, except the location which I placed them.

Could some one explain? I think calculating the MVP matrix in shader is the proper way to do thing in openGL version > 3.0 right? But I can't get it to work. The sun disappear when I applied the new code to it.

Old calculations:

```
void renderSun(int i){
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sun_TextureID);
    glUniform1i(sun_TextureLocation, 0);
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<float>(width), 0.0f, static_cast<float>(height), 1000.0f, -1000.0f);
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0, 120, 1),
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
    );
    /* Animations */
    GLfloat angle = (GLfloat) (i);
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    Model = glm::translate(Model, glm::vec3(CENTRE_X, 0.0f, CENTRE_Z));
    Model = glm::scale(Model, SUN_SIZE);
    Model = glm::rotate(Model, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    /* ******* */

    glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramSun, "mvpMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numsToDraw, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

New calculations:

```
void renderSun(int i){
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sun_TextureID);
    glUniform1i(sun_TextureLocation, 0);
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<float>(width), 0.0f, static_cast<float>(height), 1000.0f, -1000.0f);
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0, 120, 1),
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
    );
    /* Animations */
    GLfloat angle = (GLfloat) (i);
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    Model = glm::translate(Model, glm::vec3(CENTRE_X, 0.0f, CENTRE_Z));
    Model = glm::scale(Model, SUN_SIZE);
    Model = glm::rotate(Model, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    GLint modelLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramSun, "model");
    GLint viewLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramSun, "view");
    GLint projLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramSun, "projection");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(View));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Projection));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Model));
    /* ******* */

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numsToDraw, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

My vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core
precision highp float;
layout (location = 0) in vec3 sun_Position;
varying vec4 Sun_Texture_Coord;

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(sun_Position, 1.0f);
    //gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(sun_Position, 1.0);
    Sun_Texture_Coord = vec4(sun_Position, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: In principle, this _could_ work. The mistake is probably outside of the functions pasted so far, probably the GL state is not correctly set at the time these functions are called. What I spotted is that you "old" code sometimes uses "planet" where the new one uses "sun". Also note that doing the calculation in the VS is _not_ the better approach to pre-calculationg it on the CPU in the general case.

Comment: The steps to render a textured object are: setup geometry (vertices), set up shaders, set up texture (image input) and finally render the object. The code I pasted above is in render stage. Additionally, the different between old code and new code is only the place where I do MVP calculations, the steps remain the same and the old code working. Then I assume that all my calculations and order in each step are correct. Where would you think the error could be?

Comment: Also, I think that, sharing workload between GPU and CPU would increase performance. Do you think this is true?

Comment: The VS is run _per vertex_, while the calcluation on the CPU is done per object. Now it depends on how many vertices there are per object where the break-even will be.